# Why is 狗屎运 a commendatory term?

Tags: phrase

When we use 狗屎 (dog's excrement) to describe a thing, it is definitely negative. Sometimes it can also appear as a bad word.
Also, 踩到狗屎 is obviously a bad thing.
But, 狗屎运 (good fortune) is used positively.
What causes this difference?

Comment: [Baidu baike](https://baike.baidu.com/item/狗屎运/5231536?fr=aladdin) says `在中国旧社会时期，农村化肥少，大都是用粪便发酵后做肥料的。但是人的粪便往往不足，所以就有了一种现象，就是早上起来捡狗屎。那时狗屎也能卖钱的，而捡了很多狗屎的人就能卖到比较多的钱。` but without a reference.

Comment: Why do you think 狗屎運 is used *positively*? Sure, it refers to fortune and luck, but people don't usually say 狗屎運 in reference to their own luck, but with a slight hint of envy or disapproval to *someone else's* luck. I think the meaning of 狗屎 is quite obvious here.

Comment: Depending to whom this phrase is direct to, it can be used jokingly between families, close friends; enviably, or contemptibly towards any third person that was not present in the conversation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

狗屎运 is ***an accidental luck*** and some good things you don't expect suddenly come to you. It's fine to use it in informal situations, but it's still a vulgar term.  Sometimes, it can be taken in a funny way, but you should be cautious when you use it in a formal situation.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't call it commendatory -- It is more like a sarcastic way of describing the accidental luck. I would never say it as I congratulate my friends for winning the championship because I sincerely believe they deserve it. However, if I hear a classmate who does not have very good grades gets into Harvard, I would call this 狗屎运.

Answer (score 0):

I think others have explained well, I don't have much to add on, but to provide a few examples:

- 兒子,你走了狗屎運. Jack,你走了狗屎運 (Joking with families and close friends)
- 小張走了狗屎運, 中了頭獎. (Envy, jealousy over a third person's luck)
- 他是什麼料. 成功就靠那點狗屎運. (Contempt)